# Evaluate $\sqrt{a+b+\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals, irrational-numbers

Evaluate  $\sqrt{a+b+\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}}$

My attempt:

Let $\sqrt{a+b+\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$

Square both sides: $a+b+\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}=x+2\sqrt{xy}+y$

Rearrange: $\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}-2\sqrt{xy}=x+y-a-b$

That's where my lights go off.

Any leads? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not guaranteed to work, but perhaps try: $a+b = x+y$, and $4xy = 2ab + b^2$?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but: Let $c=a+b.$ Then $2ab+b^2=c^2-a^2.$

So $$\sqrt{a+b+\sqrt{2ab+b^2}}=\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c^2-a^2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking squares, you can proceed as follows
$$(a+b)+\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}=(x+y)+2\sqrt{xy}$$
Compare corresponding (conjugate) parts on both the sides of above equation, we get
$$x+y=a+b\tag 1$$
$$2\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{2ab+b^2}\iff 4xy=2ab+b^2\tag 2$$
$$x-y=\pm\sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}=\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2-(2ab+b^2)}=\pm a\tag3$$
Solving (1) & (3) we get $x$ & $y$ as follows
$$x=a+\frac{b}{2}, \ y=\frac b2\ \ \ \text{OR}\ \  \ x=\frac b2, \ y=a+\frac{b}{2}$$

Comment: How do we know that the part under sqrt is irrational and the other part as rational?

Comment: @Bhaswat you can precisely call them the corresponding parts with sq.root and without square root

Comment: And then why can you equate them individually?

Comment: The corresponding parts have to be equal for equality to hold true

Comment: $\sqrt(9)+2 =\sqrt(4)+3$ what about now?

Comment: $\sqrt{4}$ & $\sqrt{9}$ are not irrationals. equation must have rational and irrational parts on both the sides to compare

Comment: So we are back to my first question. How do we know that in this case the sqrt term is irrational?

Comment: Well, for that you have to mention conditions for $x$ & $y$ such that $x, y$ are positive reals and whether perfect square or not you have to mention.

Comment: However if $\sqrt{xy}$ is not irrational then $\sqrt{xy}$ has to be rational so $x+y+2\sqrt{xy}$ will also be rational then still the equality will have to hold

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot how did you arrive to step 3 from step 1 and 2?

Comment: $$(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy=x^2+y^2+2xy-4xy=(x+y)^2-4xy\iff \sqrt{(x-y)^2}=\sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}\iff |x-y|=\sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}\iff x-y=\pm\sqrt{(x+y)^2-4xy}$$ Substitute values of $(x+y)$ & $4xy$ from (1) & (2) to get (3)

Comment: Nice one @HarishChandraRajpoot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By conjugates $\sqrt{a+b\pm\sqrt{2ab+b^2}}=\sqrt{x}\pm\sqrt{y}$ i.e. $a+b=x+y,\,2ab+b^2=4xy$, so $x,\,y$ are roots of $t^2-(a+b)t+ab/2+b^2/4=(t-a-b/2)(t-b/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not clear what range of values is acceptable for the variables, I believe I have a sense of what you are trying to do here. This is called [denesting square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Two_nested_square_roots).

In particular, if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers such that $a^2-b^2 c$ is non-negative, then it holds that
$$\sqrt{a+ b\sqrt{c}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b^2 c}}{2}}+ \sqrt{\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2-b^2 c}}{2}}.$$
It can be easily proven by squaring both sides and using the difference of squares factorization. There is a way of coming up with it naturally by using the same idea behind finding complex square roots, though it might not be an entirely rigorous approach.

This yields
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{a+b+\sqrt{2ab+b^2}}&=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+|a|}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b-|a|}{2}}\\
&= \begin{cases} \sqrt{a+\frac{b}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{b}{2}} &\text{ if } a\ge 0\\ \sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}+\sqrt{a+\frac{b}{2}} &\text{ if } a<0\end{cases}.
\end{align*}
which works because $$(a+b)^2-1^2\cdot (2ab+b^2)=a^2$$ is non-negative. Both cases yield the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note

\begin{align}
&\sqrt{a+b+\sqrt{\left(2ab+b^2\right)}} \\
=& \sqrt{\frac{(2a+b)+b +2\sqrt{(2a+b)b}}{2}}\\
= &\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{2a+b}+\sqrt b )^2}{2}}\\
= &\sqrt{\frac{2a+b}2}+\sqrt {\frac b{2}}\\
\end{align}